# Global flag returns one result while no flag returns multiple (JS Regex HELP)

Tags: javascript, regex

I am teaching myself JS regex and am going through a series of exercises. One of which is to select strings having the correct date format. The expression I found to capture the formats i'm interested in is as follows: \d{2}[-/.]\d{2}(-/.\b

In the text editor I used for testing purposes it works just fine. In the javascript program I wrote it captures the desired date but also the the year. So if I input 12.25.2001 I would get ["12.25.2001", "2001", index: 0, input: "10.20.1990"]. That is odd for two reasons. 1) "2001" does not fit the form of the regular expression so far as I can tell and should not be selected. 2) The global flag is not enabled so it should only show the first found result anyway.

Further adding to the strangeness is the fact that when I enable the global flag I only get the one result: ["12.25.2001"]. I must be missing something obvious. I include the relevant part of my code below. Any help would be much appreciated. Once again--I can get the correct result. I want to know WHY including the /g flag works and not using it doesn't (when it seems like the opposite should be the case).

```js
 var s = mainText.value;
  var r = /\d{2}[-/\.]\d{2}[(-/\.](\d{4}|\d{2})\b/g;
  var x = s.match(r);
  console.log(x);
  if (x) {
   output.value = "Great! It's a date then!"
  }
  else {
   output.value = "Please enter a legitimate date..."
  }
```

Comment: Side note, sites like regex101.com and regexr.com are usually indispensable when it comes to learning and troubleshooting regexes for beginners

Comment: I'm not sure what the question is.  In the beginning you give `\d{2}[-/.]\d{2}(-/.\b` which is invalid, but then in your code you have `/\d{2}[-/\.]\d{2}[(-/\.](\d{4}|\d{2})\b/g` which **explicitly** checks for two digits, dot or dash, two digits, dot or dash, and then four OR two digits.  You say though, "2001 does not fit the form of the regular expression," but it does.  Like @j08691 mentioned, using [Regex101](https://regex101.com/r/7A7ndU/1) you can see what groups are captured and why.

Comment: So I have found the answer to my question. I did not know that match() would return an array *including* the groups inside of my regex expression. A way to make it behave as intended was to include ":?" at the start of the groups I want to make "non-capturing." So a final expression might look like: /\d{2}[-/\.]\d{2}[(-/\.](:?\d{4}|\d{2})\b/g